# error unknow flag --control-plane-endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy, kubernetes-pod, bare-metal-server

I'm trying to create a bare metal multimaster kubernetes cluster. The version of kubernetes I'm working with is 1.15.12. The issue I'm running into is with the command:

```
kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint "LOAD_BALANCER_DNS:LOAD_BALANCER_PORT" --upload-certs --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
```

The error is that --control-plane-endpoint is unknown.

I believe in version 1.15.12 this kubeadm flag doesn't exist. Am I using the correct flag or is there a substitute that I can use for the version that I'm using (v1.15.12)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, that flag was implemented in [Kubernetes v1.16](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.16.md):

> kubeadm: provide `--control-plane-endpoint` flag for
> `controlPlaneEndpoint` ([#79270](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/79270))

The version you are trying to use is pretty old and so it is highly recommend for you to either:

- [Upgrade your cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade/)
- Create a new cluster from scratch using a more recent version of Kubernetes (preferably v1.20). The [kubeadm init](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/) docs can help you with it, especially the `--kubernetes-version` flag: Choose a specific Kubernetes version for the control plane.

Remember that things get deprecated for a reason and keeping your cluster up to date can save you a lot of trouble in the future.